# Opengl - SpotLight shadow map issue

Tags: opengl, lighting, shadow-mapping

I have a light / shadow system that implements a spot light too.

Every lights are working fine, but the spot light is acting weird.

If i dont use any type of "shadow softening" method, it works perfectly well but (of course, the shadow is really pixelized).

Its simple:

1- When i dont use softening, i can set the spot light to a close or far range without any problem (shadow is rendering correctly).

2- When i use softening, if i am not REALLY close to the object (2 meters max), it starts cutting part off of the shadow, and if i go even further (3-4 metter) there is literally no shadow anymore (even though i could go 20 meters without softening without any problem)

Here are pictures so you can see what i mean :

On this image, i am using PCF for soft shadows and you can already see the cutoff when the spot light is close to the objects

**(In red: cutoff)  -  (In blue: spotlight position)**
[image]

And finally, when using no softening method (just basic shadow), i can be 3 times further and the shadow is perfectly visible and correct (no cut-off)

[image]

Here is my fragment shader (only the shadow calculation part)

```html
float ShadowCalculation(Light light, vec3 fragPos)
{
 vec4 fragPosLightSpace = light.lightMatrix * vec4(fragPos.xyz,1);

    // perform perspective divide
    vec3 projCoords = fragPosLightSpace.xyz / fragPosLightSpace.w;

    // Transform to [0,1] range
    projCoords = projCoords * 0.5 + 0.5;



 if(projCoords.z > 1)
  return 0.0f;

    // Get closest depth value from light's perspective (using [0,1] range fragPosLight as coords)
    float closestDepth = texture(light.shadowMap, projCoords.xy).r; 
    // Get depth of current fragment from light's perspective
    float currentDepth = projCoords.z;
    // Check whether current frag pos is in shadow

 float bias = 0.005;

 //PCF HERE (SOFT SHADOW FOR IMAGE 1 - 2)
    //float shadow = 0;
 //vec2 texelSize = 1.0 / textureSize(light.shadowMap, 0) / 50;
 //for(int x = -1; x < 1; ++x){
 // for(int y = -1; y <= 1; ++y){
 //  float pcfDepth = texture(light.shadowMap, projCoords.xy + vec2(x,y) * texelSize).r;
 //  shadow += currentDepth - bias > pcfDepth? 1.0 : 0.0;
 // }
 //}

 //shadow /= 9.0;
 
 //HARD SHADOW - IMAGE 3 (WORKING)
 float shadow = currentDepth > closestDepth  ? 1.0 : 0.0;  

    return shadow;
}
```

and my shadow class:

```html
Shadow::Shadow(e_LightType* light) {
 m_type = light;
 


 if (*m_type == e_Spotlight || *m_type == e_DirectionnalLight) {
  glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_depthMapFBO); //Create frame buffer
  m_shadowWidth = 1024; //Set shadow map size
  m_shadowHeight = 1024;
  glGenTextures(1, &m_depthMap);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_depthMap);
  //Generate the texture with gl_depth_component settings
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, m_shadowWidth, m_shadowHeight, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);

  //Set texture parameters
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);

  GLfloat borderColor[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
  glTexParameterfv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR, borderColor);


  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_depthMapFBO);
  glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_depthMap, 0);
  glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
  glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

  m_aspect = (GLfloat)m_shadowWidth / (GLfloat)m_shadowHeight;
  m_near = 0.5f;
  m_far = 100.0f;

 }


 else if (*m_type == e_PointLight) {
  glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_depthMapFBO); //Create frame buffer
  m_shadowWidth = 1024; //Set shadow map size
  m_shadowHeight = 1024;

  glGenTextures(1, &m_depthMap);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, m_depthMap);

  for (GLuint i = 0; i < 6; ++i) { //MAYBE ERROR WITH ++I
   glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, m_shadowWidth, m_shadowHeight, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
  }

  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);


  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_depthMapFBO);
  glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, m_depthMap, 0);

  glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
  glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);

  if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
   std::cout << "Framebuffer not complete!" << "\n";

  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

  m_aspect = (GLfloat)m_shadowWidth / (GLfloat)m_shadowHeight;
  m_near = 0.5f;
  m_far = 500.0f;
  SetShadowProjection();
 }
}
```

This is not about the rendering, so i am not gonna put non-relevant code other than this.

I also tried to change the near  - far and the problem persist....

Help!

Comment: why are you calculating the fragment's clip space position in the fragment shader? Usually you calculate the vertex position in clip space by multiplying the vertex local coordinates with the object's model matrix and the light's view and projection matrix in the vertex shader. Then you have the homogeneous clip space coordinates for the fragment in the fragment shader and perform the perpsective divide to get the normalized device coordinates [-1, 1]. Then you transform to get the values in the [0,1] range and perform the depth test.
I'm not sure what fragPos is.